# How to remove elements from a text box using jQuery that is added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three textboxes which is holding the values that are dynamically generated.
I am able to do the adding of elements to the textbox which is working properly.
I also have one function which is removing the generated textboxes, but my problem is that I cannot remove the elements which was added previously to the textboxes when removing.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/08uq09cL/1/)

```
   $("#btnGet").bind("click", function () {
    var valuesarr = new Array();
    var phonearr = new Array();
    var phonearr1 = new Array();
    $("input[name=DynamicTextBox]").each(function () {
        valuesarr.push($(this).val());
        $('#DynamicTextBox').val(valuesarr);
    });
    $("input[name=phoneNum]").each(function () {
        phonearr.push($(this).val());
        $('#phoneNum').val(phonearr);
    });

    $("input[name=phoneNum1]").each(function () {
        phonearr1.push($(this).val());
        $('#phoneNum1').val(phonearr1);
    });

    alert(valuesarr);
    alert(phonearr);
    alert(phonearr1);
});
```

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear; to me, at least. I would suggest editing your post to make it clearer *what* the problem is you're having, and *what* you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Matt ok i am editing

Comment: What do you mean by element? Text? Call it text then. Element is typically synonymous with an object, like in this case the textbox

Comment: Are you trying to remove the three texboxes that are there from the beginning? If so, what is the problem you're running into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("body").on("click", ".remove", function () {
        $(this).closest("div").remove();
        UpdateData();
    });
```

After removing should update again